# Question regarding user etiquette in answers and comments

Tags: discussion, etiquette, users

*Update*

Note the OP appears to have deleted the inciting comments.

I vote to close my own question but appreciate very much the comments to date.

Please see this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/284691/1997)

In particular, refer to my deleted answer.

Firstly, I regret my triggered response. I state extreme overwork and illness as mitigating factors. This is not an excuse but a context.

Secondly, I merely converted a complex analysis problem to a surface integral. The surface was flat and the surface element reduces to the Jacobian determinant that I used. Of course, I accept I may be deficient or made a stupid error.

I was extremely offended by the manner of the reply. I respect and have always owned my mistakes. Mistakes are opportunities to learn. The comments were spiteful and made pejorative assumptions.

I reject completely that they were constructive.

I request clarification re: post etiquette asserted by OP and user-user etiquette.

I have tried to dutifully participate in this forum. I have learned a lot. I have made stupid (unforgivable) errors. I do not claim otherwise. I merely assert users should act with respect.

**Update 20 June 2023**

See my [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/286730/1997) and the comment.

To be fair,

1. It is true I combined prior knowledge with Mathematica as a tool to achieve a specific goal (not a general one). I do not know a general algorithm to generate Cayley graph for arbitrary groups.
2. Perhaps, my code is opaque.
3. I may have overall misunderstood the intent of question.
4. I may have misunderstood the point of the site.

I am not going to engage in debate but acknowledge above.

I interpret the site as helping people with questions. Answers, from my experience of the site, can be specific or general; can motivate better answers; promote learning; can be an interaction between human reason and Mathematica. I also believe there is diversity in users on site. This was a strength.

If the aims of site and user expectations have changed, I cam limit or withdraw my engagement to prevent corruption of site standard.  I have found the site and answering questions a source of education for me as well as frankly fun.

I obviously am perceived, by this user, as some blight. Everyone is allowed their opinion. I admit to very limited knowledge. However, one thing this site seemed to allow was development/improvement and learning through participation no matter what the level of user.

My reputation points are reflections of enthusiasm more than skill/merit.
I will think about continued participation, probably visit but not answer so much.

For the record, the commentary that initiated the original post coincided with me developing COVID for the first time in this pandemic, and despite early antivirals remain unwell. I was uncertain about the pathophysiological basis of long COVID but perhaps I am a datapoint.

In the interest of peace, I acknowledge other user may have a point  and I will contemplate the manner of continued participation in a site that I have enjoyed.

Comment: (Heavily opinionated comment ahead) I don't think you did anything wrong in your answer, especially not something deserving such a comment. I found the OP to often be very confrontative, bordering on rude or insulting. Whether that is due to some language barrier or something else I don't know, but I have stopped taking their comments too seriously.

Comment: You requested clarification... We have [code of conduct](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/conduct). I'd say that the OP's comment verged on violating the policy of "no subtle put-downs or unfriendly language".

Comment: Thank you to users who took time to reply. What’s done is done. My reaction potentially inflamed situation. However, it was triggered (I Hope understandably). I appreciate I have a habit of terse answers, esp of late. It is a time issue. Note I am also in timezone GMT + 10 hours. This weekend is dedicated to my grandchildren. I hope the community will continue to be diverse and operate with a foundation of mutual respect.

Comment: Ha! Ha!  Join the club!  I, too, have received several such impertinent comments from that OP.  But there was an occasion where I was too loose in one of my responses and that OP corrected me.  Blunt, but correct.  So like @LukasLang I now don't take those comments personally but I do make sure I understand those comments and I admit I do take some joy in the rare occasion that can point out an error made by that OP.

Comment: I appreciate this is a sensitive question .I understand reluctance to answer.  I am grateful for the comments. I should have demonstrated ‘thicker skin’ but I genuinely believe the comments were not  constructive but were demeaning. As an average citizen of this community I have very much valued the diversity of users, answers, approaches. It is bonus to see and sometimes participate in the rarefied air of the very high end users.  Comments that call users ‘uncivilized’ or give links implying need for re-education are not, to my mind, in the spirit of the community.

Comment: @JimB #MeToo. :) @ ubpdqn, I don't reply to the OP, neither to answer questions nor to answer comments. At some point I realized it would be too much unnecessary work to deal with. I tend to avoid Q&A in which they are actively "debating" everyone else. I used to think I was overly tolerant of this person, cutting them slack for probably not being a native English speaker and perhaps neurodiverse. At some point I wrote, "Stop being a jerk," which offended them. And I feel that was a good thing. Being offended serves a purpose. And they stopped engaging with me, for a while at least.

Comment: I can not see a record of the offending content, so I don't think it's possible to comment (let alone pass judgement) for anybody that didn't witness the exchange at the time. If you did wrong, first that is no justification for receiving abuse and second, it's good to see you admit them, even if from my vantage point one can hardly understand whats happening here. What is the question that can be answered here?

Comment: @rhermans thank you for your comment. In the OP comments he asserted it was ‘civilized’ to use a particular format: implying it was etiquette. Secondly, his comment and hyperlink were inflammatory. As I see I am not the only to experience this. You are probably right that there is no corrective action that would mitigate this. I was hoping for more than “suck it up princess”. The question is this user comment behaviour acceptable? You don’t believe there was an issue.I can understand that and that you see the question, therefore, as vacuous.

Comment: @rhermans it appears the inflammatory comment has been deleted. I now understand your comment.

Comment: Just gonna join the chorus (probably unhelpfully) that the specific OP there has a track record of making inflammatory, rarely helpful, often technically incorrect, verging on troll-y comments that have ground the gears of many users here. Obviously any sort of angry response is regrettable and with that poster in particular it is wisest not to engage, but given the history I think you have nothing to apologize for and your contribution was helpful

Comment: Ah, it is about _that_ guy. Hehe. I've had my struggles with them, too. I also don't know what to do about them. The comment isn't there anymore, so I cannot judge how severe it was. I can only recommend to flag such comments in the future. Then the moderators know about the incident and have a track record. Maybe that will allow them to justify some actions beyond just removing that comment, e.g., a temporary ban or so.

Comment: This has been a problem that pops up from time to time now for years. Based on the [code of conduct](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/conduct), I'm surprised more action hasn't been taken.

Comment: Who is *that guy*?

Comment: @rhermans I don’t know. I believe he has been temporarily suspended. He has been a long term user and made positive contributions (as well as challenging comments). Hopefully, we can all move to more constructive approach in the future.

Comment: Code of conduct has been [updated](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/conduct)

Comment: @ubpdqn, regarding your update, I suggest you don't spend any more time contemplating about this user and his distasteful comments—or even thinking about leaving the site because of it! As you can see from many comments above, he has annoyed several respectable users of this site, and it seems his latest suspension didn't have much effect ...

Comment: For whatever it's worth, I second @Domen 's comment. Don't leave us!